# Plane Wave expansion method

Tags: waves, photons, computational-physics, software, crystals

I really don't know if this is the right forum to ask the question...but please help me if you can!!

I was going through the Plane Wave Expansion Method Derivation...But to be honest I could not find any step by step proof of this method. (If you provide me one!! I would be thankful)

Next coming to the derivation given in the link below, while going through the derivation, I could not understand where come the components $G_i + G_{i'} \rightarrow G_{i'}$ could be written, and similarly the lines which follow it. Similarly ,how do we introduce $G_i,\ G_{i'},\ G_{ii}$...

It would be really helpful if anybody could help me out on this one...

Lastly I would also appreciate if anyone could just typeset the question properly as I am new here!!

[PWM Manual](http://www.phys.ubbcluj.ro/~emil.vinteler/nanofotonica/PWM/pwmmanual_Guo.pdf)

Comment: As per the plane-wave expansion: please see [the third section of this pdf](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221B-S02/bessel.pdf) and let me know if you have any questions about the derivation. I would be happy to clarify any specific questions, but do not want to type out what is already nicely done here. Also, in the second part, do you mean $G_i,\ G_{i'},\ G_{i''}$ ?

Comment: Yes!! I mean $G_i,\ G_{i'},\ G_{ii}$ what does that actually mean?? Also i would like to know its physical interpretation of the $G_i,\ G_{i'},\ G_{ii}$ would really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term $G_{i} + G_{i'} \rightarrow G_{i'}$ in the manual can be used because the structure which is under analysis is a periodic multi layered structure.Due to its periodicity the different indexes of summation can be grouped and coupled or reduced to a single summation index.